# Netplan 2 Interfaces, same IP Load Balance?

Tags: networking, server, netplan

Is there a way to load balance with netplan between 2 interfaces that have the same IPs in my machine?

My current configuration is like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      optional: true
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses:
        - 192.168.3.9/24
        - "2601:19b:4700:17c::1002/128"
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 1.1.1.1
          - 1.0.0.1
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
          - "2606:4700:4700::1111"
          - "2606:4700:4700::1001"
          - "2001:4860:4860::8888"
          - "2001:4860:4860::8844"
      routes:   
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.3.1
          metric: 100
  wifis:
    wlp4s0:
      optional: true
      access-points:
        "MY_SSID":
          password: "MY_PASS"
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses:
        - 192.168.3.9/24
        - "2601:19b:4700:17c::1002/128"
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 1.1.1.1
          - 1.0.0.1
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
          - "2606:4700:4700::1111"
          - "2606:4700:4700::1001"
          - "2001:4860:4860::8888"
          - "2001:4860:4860::8844"
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.3.1
          metric: 200
```

Comment: With bonding you only assign the IP to the bond and not the interfaces.  I don't know if bonding a WiFi and an Ethernet is wise, but I am sure it can be done.  For the bonding though you will need to decide why you are doing it and what is the best bonding type you will need.  See:  https://www.hughesportal.com/blog.php?article=setup-network-bonding-using-netplan

Comment: Thanks Terrance, I am thinking I'd like the Ethernet as the backup, I think that is what I am looking for ;)   My WIfi on that machine is 2-4x faster than my Ethernet is, so I'll likely set it up as an `active-backup`  I'm not at this server right now, and my internet is down anyways, so, I can't test yet...  can you post as an answer though?